# php-fpm getallheaders() in lower case

Tags: php

I am using getallheaders() function in **php:7.3-apache** dockerfile.

As per the documentation, PHP is converting all headers keys into lower cases. It is working fine.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('getallheaders'))
{
    function getallheaders()
    {
           $headers = [];
       foreach ($_SERVER as $name => $value)
       {
           if (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'HTTP_')
           {
               $headers[str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', substr($name, 5)))))] = $value;
           }
       }
       return $headers;
    }
}
?>
```

When I am trying the same code with php-fpm it is giving camel case header keys.

```
<?php
    echo var_export(getallheaders());
?>
```

How can I get the same lower case header keys in PHP-FPM also?

Comment: If it is just an array `array_map('strtolower', ..` should work

Comment: getallheaders is php inbuilt function. i dont want modify my all code after getallheader() function. is there any same function available in php-fpm also?